# Typescript and ReactJS: previous state how to make it work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble making the previous state on React 18 working with Typescript version 4.8.3.

This is my refreshToken code and I get the **error** :

> Value of type '(prev: any) => any' has no properties in common with
> type 'IUserData'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)

on (prev: any), So I tried adding prev in my 'IUserData' (useAuth() is related to IUserData), but it doesn't work...

```
const useRefreshToken = () => {
    const { setAuth } = useAuth();

    const refresh = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/refresh', {
            withCredentials: true 
        });
        setAuth((prev: any) => { 
            return { 
                ...prev, 
                role: response.data.idRole, 
                accessToken: response.data.accessToken }
        });
        return response.data.accessToken;
    }
    return refresh;
};

export default useRefreshToken;
```

My IUserData interface:

```
export interface IUserData {
    id?: number
    email?: string
    role?: number
    accessToken?: string
    auth?: {id?: number
        email?: string
        role?: number
        accessToken?: string
    }
    setAuth?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IUserData>>
    setPersist?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>> | Dispatch<any>
}
```

When I try with (prev: IUserData) I get the **error** :

> Value of type '(prev: IUserData) => { accessToken: any; id?: number | undefined; email?: string | undefined; role?: number | undefined; auth?: { id?: number | undefined; email?: string | undefined; role?: number | undefined; accessToken?: string | undefined; } | undefined; setAuth?: Dispatch<...> | undefined; setPersist?: Dispatch...' has no properties in common with type 'IUserData'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)

AuthProvider.tsx :

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({});

interface props {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: props) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<IUserData>({});
    const [persist, setPersist] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist")!) || false);
        
    return (
         <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth, persist, setPersist }}> 
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change the type in setAuth inside of IUserData

For example:

```
type AuthData = {
    id?: number
    email?: string
    role?: number
    accessToken?: string
}

export interface IUserData {
    id?: number
    email?: string
    role?: number
    accessToken?: string
    auth?: AuthData,
    setAuth?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<AuthData>>
    setPersist?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>> | Dispatch<any>
}
```

and remove the "any" type from your prevState

```
...
setAuth((prev) => { 
  return { 
    ...prev, 
    role: response.data.idRole, 
    accessToken: response.data.accessToken 
  }
});
...
```

You also need to change the type of your useState inside your AuthProvider, so change the IUserData for AuthData like below.

```
...
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<AuthData>({});
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried with your suggestion, added the type AuthData and used `setAuth((prev) =>` , but I still get the error _"(parameter) prev: any
Value of type '(prev: any) => any' has no properties in common with type 'AuthData'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)
Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.ts(7024)
Parameter 'prev' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)"_
I will add my AuthProvider code above if it can help...

Comment: Ooh ok, I edited my answer above, basically, you need to change the type in your useState inside the AuthProvider.

Comment: thanks for your help. It still was showing an error, so I found another solution: `setAuth({...auth,
           role: response.data.idRole,  
            accessToken: response.data.accessToken
        }); `